# Social Logout Google Plus Issue in iOS

Tags: ios

logout from google plus I used **disconnect** method but after that sign in app directly goes to permission page. Doesn't ask for Login. why?

```
here is my Sign In function

-(google*) MethodgoogleLogin
{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"gotGoogleErrorAppClosed" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                               selector:@selector(gotGoogleErrorAppClosed:) name:@"gotGoogleErrorAppClosed" object:nil];

obj_google = [[google alloc]init];
personName=[[GTLPlusPersonName alloc]init];

// google + code
signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  

signIn.clientID = @"384945330563-pcls0t8c28s1jf7qiod9555sg7edfqhj.apps.googleusercontent.com";


signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ]; 

signIn.delegate = obj_google;
[signIn authenticate];

 return obj_google;
}
```

here is my sign out function

```
-(void)signOut
{
  [signIn disconnect];
  [signIn signOut];
}
```

Comment: May be you are logged in to your google account from your browser in some other tab , than it might directly lead you to permission page without asking for credentials

Answer (score 1):

You can use the signOut method of the GPPSignIn object to sign out your user, for example:

```
 - (void)signOut {
      [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
      }
```

and after this revoke the token and disconnect the app.
For more information visit this:- https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#sign_out_the_user

Comment: I have checked that link. I have used signOut and disconnect both method but it doesn't work.